# displaying the country with the smallest area from a file in C++

Tags: c++

my task is to write a program to read a file called countries.txt which contains a number of countries and their respective land areas and then display the country with the largest and smallest land areas. I am having trouble displaying the country with the smallest land area and would be more then grateful if someone is able to show me how to do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ins;   // declare an input file stream object
    
    ins.open("/Users/daneided/Desktop/countries.txt");  // open the file by pasting the path
    if (ins.fail()) {     // program to check if the file failed to open
        cout << "Error opening file";
        return -1;
    }
    
    string biggestCountry;   // name of the biggest country
    int biggestArea = 0; // the country with the biggest area
   
  
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   // read five lines from the file
        string countryName;
        int area;
        ins >> countryName >> area;  // read 2 variables from the stream line
        
        if (area > biggestArea) {   // update the current maximum if greater
            biggestArea = area;
            biggestCountry = countryName;
        }
        
    }
    
    
        
    ins.close();   // close the file
        
        cout << "Biggest country is: " << biggestCountry <<
        " (" << biggestArea << ") " << endl;
        
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You figured out the largest, now do the same for the smallest, or just use `std::sort` and be done with it, picking off the resulting first and last entries.

Comment: That'll be virtually the same except you'll set the `smallestArea` variable to something very big initially and then use `<` for that where you are using `>` for biggest.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError You can also treat the "smallest" as the "highest negative number" as in comparing `-area` instead. That works even better with floats since you won't need to bust out "infinity".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this belkow your if for the biggest country, you should get the hang of it from here:

```
int smallestArea = biggestArea; /* because you need a default value that is greater then the minimum area of the smallest country   */

if (area < smallestArea) {  
                smallestArea = area;
                smallestCountry = countryName;
            }
```